# Get a selected font in a subclassed QFontDialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to subclass QFontDialog and would like to retrieve the characteristics of the selected font. If I use getFont() a QFontDialog window appears first, ... I'm certainly doing something wrong.

Here's my example code :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QFontDialog, QPushButton, 
                            QMainWindow, QApplication, 
                            QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout)

import sys

class FontSelection(QFontDialog) :
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FontSelection, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setOption(self.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        
        self.bouton = self.findChildren(QPushButton)
        self.intitule_bouton = self.bouton[0].text().lower()
        self.ouvertureBouton = [x for x in self.bouton if self.intitule_bouton in str(x.text()).lower()][0]
        self.ouvertureBouton.clicked.disconnect()
        self.ouvertureBouton.clicked.connect(self.font_recup)
        
        
    def font_recup(self) :
        self.font_capture()
        
        
    def font_capture(self) :
        if self.intitule_bouton in ['ok', '&ok'] : 
            font, self.intitule_bouton = self.getFont()
            print(font)
            
            
class MainQFontDialogTry(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainQFontDialogTry, self).__init__()
    
        self.setWindowTitle('QFontDialog subclassed try')
    
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 760)
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 760)
    
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
    
        self.win_widget_1 = FontSelection(self)

        widget = QWidget()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.win_widget_1, "QFontDialog Tab")
    
        layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
        self.qfont = FontSelection()
        self.qfont.font_recup()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainQFontDialogTry()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here, but I can see more than one problem: first of all, `getFont()` is a *static* method, which (as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html#getFont)) "Executes a modal font dialog and returns a font", which means that a **new dialog** would be shown immediately. Then the whole mechanism of buttons is really obscure, what are trying to achieve there? Finally, trying to embed a QDialog (created by Qt, not you) inside another widget is rarely a good idea, and has more risks than benefits.

Comment: Ok so I got it all wrong. In fact I would like to recover all the fonts installed on the system, to be able to select the type of font, the font style and the size and with a button to recover all that. I would like to either subclass QFontDialog and get the selected font back, or use another solution without going through QFontDialog. I'm (also) currently looking at QFontDatabase, maybe that would be a solution.

Comment: @ekdmekdm Why can't you just use `QFontDialog.getFont()` to select a font? Why do you think you need to subclass QFontDialog? What *specifically* do you expect that to do that `getFont` can't?